# Does hibernate load two seprate copies of same instance if they are loaded twice from database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know there are many different question on SO regarding lazy load but mine one is a bit different.

Lets say i have an entity A in which i have collection of Entity B. Similarly, in Entity B, i have collection of A. In both case, lazy="true" option is used.

**Entity A**'s instace aA has -->`Set<B>`===(This set contains Entity B's instance bB)

**Entity B**'s instace bB has -->`Set<A>`===(This set contains Entity A's instance aA)

Now if i load Entity A's collection(Which is `Set<B>` ).Its initialized now, i.e. complete A's aA instance including collection. What i expect now is Entity B's instance bB is also completely initialized but no, its not and i get lazy initialization exception when i refer Entity B's collection which has Entity A's instance aA.

Does hibernate load two seprate copies of same instance if they are loaded twice from database? if so, is there a way to synchronize changes in all copies within session?

Hope i am clear enough and haven't messed things up with messy info:)

Comment: with `lazy=true`, loading `A` will lazily load `B`, but in 'B', only identifiers will be loaded `(ie b.id)`, but we need to separately intialize the lzy collection using `HIbernate.intialize(a.getB());`

Comment: It would most likely be a performance hit with little added value.

Comment: Could you explain why you expect that? If I understand, you expect that if one thing is lazily initialized, then everything else in the entire session should be initialized instantly?

Comment: No , i don't expect that if one thing is lazily initialized, then everything else in the entire session should be initialized instantly. What i expected is that there would be single copy of any particular instance in entire session.  So i do expect that if A's instance aA  is completely initalized then aA should be automatically initalized wherever its copy exist, in this case in Set of entity B.

Comment: Yes, that part of your expectations is true. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Does hibernate load two seprate copies of same instance if they are loaded twice from database?

No, it won't load the same object twice (for our sanity's sake) in the same Session.

I've created a simple [Spring Boot project](https://github.com/gabrielgiussi/so-31045875/tree/1.2) to see this.

```
EntityA#setOfB(B1,B2)
EntityB#setOfA(A1)
```

After load EntityA 1 and EntityB to Session by ID, we force A1.setOfB initialization.
In the log below we can see that altough it has to query the collection obtaining both rows (B1 & B2), it will only hidrate one object (B2) because B1 is found in the Session Cache. See test 1 (mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="1")

```
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.g.hiplay.app.HibernateService          : ########## Retrieving A1's set of B ##########
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select setofb0_.id_a as id_a1_0_0_, setofb0_.id_b as id_b2_2_0_, entityb1_.id as id1_1_1_, entityb1_.description as descript2_1_1_ from relations setofb0_ inner join entityb entityb1_ on setofb0_.id_b=entityb1_.id where setofb0_.id_a=?
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.i.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader  : Bound [2] parameters total
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Constructing collection load context for result set [rs3: org.h2.result.LocalResult@5c99abd7 columns: 4 rows: 2 pos: -1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Starting attempt to find loading collection [[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection not yet initialized; initializing
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Processing result set
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Starting attempt to find loading collection [[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Attempting to locate loading collection entry [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] in any result-set context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Collection [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] located in load context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Found loading collection bound to current result set processing; reading row
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Loading entity: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Attempting to resolve: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Resolved object in session cache: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#1]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #1
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] l.p.e.p.i.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl : hydrating entity state
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] l.p.e.p.i.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl : Initializing object from ResultSet: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Hydrating entity: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Starting attempt to find loading collection [[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Attempting to locate loading collection entry [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] in any result-set context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Collection [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] located in load context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Found loading collection bound to current result set processing; reading row
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Loading entity: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Attempting to resolve: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Resolved object in session cache: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Done processing result set (2 rows)
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.e.p.internal.AbstractRowReader   : Total objects hydrated: 1
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Attempting to locate loading collection entry [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB.setOfA#2]] in any result-set context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Collection [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB.setOfA#2]] not located in load context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB.setOfA#2]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityB#2]
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Attempting to locate loading collection entry [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] in any result-set context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : Collection [CollectionKey[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]] located in load context
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Removing collection load entry [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadingCollectionEntry<rs=rs3: org.h2.result.LocalResult@5c99abd7 columns: 4 rows: 2 pos: 2, coll=[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]>@131c8e88]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Ending loading collection [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadingCollectionEntry<rs=rs3: org.h2.result.LocalResult@5c99abd7 columns: 4 rows: 2 pos: 2, coll=[oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]>@131c8e88]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB#1]
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: oss.gabrielgiussi.hiplay.entities.EntityA.setOfB
TRACE 6452 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.StatefulPersistenceContext       : Initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG 6452 --- [           main] o.g.hiplay.app.HibernateService          : ########## The object hasn't been loaded twice ##########
```

Hibernate checks if the [Object to hydrate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.java#L1542) is already in the Session Cache [asking to the StatefulPersistenceContext](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.java#L598)

> What i expect now is Entity B's instance bB is also completely initialized but no, its not and i get lazy initialization exception when i refer Entity B's collection which has Entity A's instance aA.

What is truly uninitialized is bB's set of A. After doing something like:

EntityA aA = session.get("A",a)
aA.setOfB.size() // force initialization of lazy collection. At this point bB is hydratate and put in memory, but his collection of A is uninitalized.

[image]

If you try to access an element of the collection Hibernate needs to initialize the collection (all it has until now is a proxy with the intelligence of load the collection from database when is needed, e.g. asking for an element or the size of the collection). See test 3 (mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="2")

```
// outside of the transaction
EntityB bB = aA.setOfB().get(0)
bB.setOfA().size() // LazyInitializationExample
```

[image]

If you were inside of a transaction the collection will be initialized and the row corresponding to aA will be retrieved from the base again but it will not be hydrated. See test 3 (mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="3")

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The flow is like this:

1. You load `aA` and `aB`. Their collections are lazy and proxied.
2. You initialize `aA`'s collection. Among others, it contains instance `aB` and it is the same one you already loaded before (the same Java object). The collection in `aB` instance **is still uninitialized**; you didn't access it, so Hibernate doesn't waste time to initialize it. At this time, it is unknown in this session that `aA` is a member of `aB`'s collection.
3. You access (initialize) `aB`'s collection. Among others, it contains instance `aA` and it is the same one you already loaded before (the same Java object).

As you can see, there are no duplicates in the current session (persistence context). There may be different proxies/collections, but they all delegate to/contain the same entity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate, as well as JPA, guarantees that there won't be two copies of one object in the session (entity manager).
However, you can always get two or more copies of one object in memory, by clearing session or directly detaching your entity from session (`session.evict()`) and loading it once more.
So you can think that only one copy of entity is persitent.
Only this copy is synchronized with database.
You can reattach detached entity once more by calling `session.merge()`, but notice that this method always returns copy of an entity, possibly different than the original one.
If there is the persistent copy of an entity, you simply get it.
BWT, to determine whether entity is persistent, you can call `session.contains()`.

There are several bugs in Hibernate that sometimes cause two or more persistent copies of an entity to appear in session, related to inheritance.
First, you load the normal copy of an entity.
Second, you load another entity that has lazy @ManyToOne relation to the first entity.
Third, you follow the reference, and get another copy of the first entity!
So either don't use inheritance in Hibernate or don't use Hibernate.
Consider using EclipseLink, since it does not have such bug.

Comment: Consider rewording `always return a new copy` because it does not do this `always` and it is unspecified whether the instance is `new` or not.

Comment: @SteveC yes, you are right. I meant that merge returns instance that may differ from the original one, and you should always use the new instance instead of the old one, since old one might be detached. Of course, Hibernate can either return the same instance, create a new one or return the existing persistent entity.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexey Andreev described, if you use session.evict(), you could have two copies of the same entity.
I'id like to give a feedback since it actually happened to me as a bug in my application wich came as : "InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity are being merged".

The thing is, I have a model like this (not all code is displayed for a clear reading purpose) :

```
public class A{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> b;
}

public class B {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_fk")
    private A a;
}
```

There is a bidirectionnal relationship between an A and multiple Bs.

As you can see, A contains a Collection of B (with a default fetchType LAZY). So when I load an entity A, it doesn't request the data for the collection of B, unless I try to get the content of the collection. Once I get the collection of B, for each B, the corresponding A is aggressively loaded (default fetchType EAGER).

So in a normal case, if I load an instance of A entity, and then I access the content of its B collection, each instance of B will have the same instance of A, wich is the original one, because in Hibernate cache, the entity A is present.

But, if I evict my instance of A from the Hibernate session (Hibernate.evict(aInstance);) BEFORE I access the B collection, and then merge it back and try to access the collection, the Hibernate cache has been cleared, so for each B, there is a new database call to find the corresponding A.
And in this case a new instance of the same entity is created, thus leading to the Exception I got when trying to save the overall objects.

I came with multiple solutions to this problem :

1. initialize the collection before I evict (Hibernate.initialize(a.getB();)
2. aggressively load the collection (fetcType EAGER) (bad practice wich could lead to performance issues)